# @Transactional not working in my Spring Tool Suit

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a issue with my project in Spring Tool Suit. @Transactional annotation is not working.

Here is my project structure:-

**web.xml:-**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**servlet-context.xml:-**

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.project.dateandcrud" />
```

**root-context.xml:-**

```
<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:datasource-cfg.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${ds.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${ds.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${ds.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${ds.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.project.dateandcrud.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean> 

<!-- Transaction Manager to make Transaction Support-->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

I have used the DAOIMPL as follows:-

```
@Repository
public class ProfileDaoImpl implements ProfileDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Session session;

@Override
@Transactional
public void addProfile(Profile p) {

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
//      session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(p);
//      session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

}
```

When I am not using @Transactional annotation my project works fine. But when using the annotaion it doesn't work.

Is there any problem in my servlet-context.xml or root-context.xml file.

I have tried moving the 
`<context:component-scan base-package="com.project.dateandcrud" />` this from **selvlet-context.xml** into **root-context.xml** but that didn't work either.

Please suggest me the possible fault.

Comment: what does it mean it does not work? is there any exception poping out?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski no error popups, just it doesnot insert the data into database...

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to open/close hibernate `session` by yourself, let `spring-tx` deal with this:

```
@Transactional
public void addProfile(Profile p) {
    final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(p);
}
```

And move `<annotation-driven/>` from `servlet-context.xml` to your `root-context.xml` configuration.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: but when i do that following error popups:- Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Comment: @Space yeah, you're right. I just have a closer look on your configuration and updated my answer.

Comment: eventually after some tweaks, it worked...please view my answer...thanks Bodhdan

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i have found....Just move the `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>` from **root-context.xml** into **servlet-context.xml**...